# Building conda package: The package must be rebuilt with conda-build > 2.0

Tags: python, conda, packaging, python-packaging, conda-build

I am running into a problem with conda packaging. I use [someone's recipe](https://github.com/strets123/libvips-conda-recipe/) to build a python binding to a C++ library, `libvips`. When I run a build (within a fresh docker image) I am getting following error:

```
Build prefix failed with prefix length 255
WARNING:conda_build.environ:Build prefix failed with prefix length 255
WARNING conda_build.environ:create_env(877): Build prefix failed with prefix length 255
Error was:
WARNING:conda_build.environ:Error was:
WARNING conda_build.environ:create_env(878): Error was:
Placeholder of length '80' too short in package /opt/conda/conda-bld/libvips_1561659686802/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_place/bin/csslint-0.6.
The package must be rebuilt with conda-build > 2.0.
```

First of all, I made sure that conda-build is a right version, and re-build `glib` before building the actual package of interest:

```
conda build version:
conda-build 3.18.5
 ---> e0cee3638360
Step 11/12 : RUN conda install -c anaconda glib
 ---> Running in ba9e7daa8d74
```

The installation of GLib runs well, but the next `conda build` fails with the same error. This leaves me wondering whether `glib` it is referring to (in `meta.yaml` under `requirements:  build:`) is different from conda `glib` package and how to specify the package source.

Comment: Use `conda build --debug` and check the output for additional information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

libvips and pyvips now have [official conda packages](https://github.com/conda-forge/libvips-feedstock). You should just be able to do:

```
conda install --channel conda-forge pyvips
```

And it'll download and install everything.

It includes a libvips binary with most optional packages enabled, including things like `openslide` and `matio`. It is currently missing `libheif` and `libjpeg-turbo`, but perhaps they will come.

Windows support is blocked on `gdk-pixbuf`, unfortunately. The [pyvips README](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips) has some notes on Windows install.